# Change from URL to Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I already have created one subdomain (store.mydomain.com), but I can not access to this subdomain and I just access this through mydomain.com/store. How can I fix it?. Please help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the database is a table called `wp-options` there you can change the `siteurl` and the `homeurl`

Otherwise you`ve the option to change it via variables in the wp-config.php file in your root. Insert this two lines.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```

Comment: Thank you. t have already created a subdomain before. But when I access this subdomain in the browser, an error is "This site can’t be reached, the server IP address could not be found.". I don't know your point. Please explain in detail. Thanks